# Performance of the first vs second call of a function

Tags: compilation, julia, dynamic-compilation

Consider the following piece of code (Julia)

```
bar(x) = for i = 1:9999 x+x*x-x+x end # Define the "bar" function
print("First try: "); @time bar(0.5)
print("Second try: "); @time bar(0.5)
bar(x) = for i = 1:9999 x+x*x-x+x end # Redefine the same "bar" function
print("Third try: "); @time bar(0.5)
print("Fourth try: "); @time bar(0.6)
```

The output is

```
First try: elapsed time: 0.002738996 seconds (88152 bytes allocated)
Second try: elapsed time: 3.827e-6 seconds (80 bytes allocated)
Third try: elapsed time: 0.002907554 seconds (88152 bytes allocated)
Fourth try: elapsed time: 2.395e-6 seconds (80 bytes allocated)
```

**Why is the second (and fourth) try so much faster (and take up less memory) than the first (and third) try?**

Comment: Julia has, I understand, a just-in-time compiler. So the first (and third) run is compiling the code (with the allocations needed for that) and the second (and fourth) runs are just running the previously compiled code.

Comment: Off-topic: what happens if you rerun the code, without modifying it? Python creates .pyc files (kind of compiled sourcecode). If the pyc files still match the source file, it won't have to recompile it again (well, not everything again). => faster

Comment: Oh ok. That totally makes sense. I would have thought that compilation would happen at the definition of the function and not at the first time to run. You can make an answer out of your comment I guess. Thanks @Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Julia has, I understand, a just-in-time compiler. So the first (and third) run is compiling the code (with the allocations needed for that) and the second (and fourth) runs are just running the previously compiled code

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand on Paul's answer: a big part of the speedup comes from Julia's type inference and multiple dispatch. Say the first time you evaluate the function with a float: the JIT (just in time compiler) figures out the type of the argument and writes an appropriate LLVM code. If you then evaluate the same function with an integer, this compiles a different LLVM code. The following times you call the function, it will dispatch different LLVM code depending on the type of the argument. This is the reason why it wouldn't make sense in general to compile when you define the function.

You can read more about this [here](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/methods/) for example (there's tons of references to multiple dispatch in the documentation!)

Consider, for example:

```
bar(x) = for i = 1:9999 x+x*x-x+x end

print("First try with floats: "); @time bar(0.5)
print("Second try with floats: "); @time bar(0.5)

print("First try with integers: "); @time bar(1)
print("Second try with integers: "); @time bar(1)
```

which gives:

```
First try with floats: elapsed time: 0.005570773 seconds (102440 bytes allocated)
Second try with floats: elapsed time: 5.762e-6 seconds (80 bytes allocated)    
First try with integers: elapsed time: 0.003584026 seconds (86896 bytes allocated)    
Second try with integers: elapsed time: 6.402e-6 seconds (80 bytes allocated)
```